# Mysql: order using greatest on timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to sort my records using the biggest timestamp between 2 tables.
For now I'm using the following `order` condition :

```
ORDER BY 
    GREATEST(
        IFNULL(tableA.create_time, 0), 
        IFNULL(tableB.create_time, 0)
    ) 
DESC
```

But the results are not sorted at all when the query is performed. What am i missing?

(I'm using `IFNULL` because the timestamp can also be `NULL`)

**Edit**

As I said in the comments when I select the greatest to see it's value, in the result I get '2014-0' instead of '2014-08-14 17:04:39'

Here's a [Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43f1c/1) or even a [simpler one with the same problem](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7729f/2)

Comment: Can you share some data so we see what's going on there?

Comment: what is the data type of create_time ?

Comment: It should work as you've written it, can you make a sqlfiddle?

Comment: both fields are timestamp and yes I'll do a sqlfiddle

Comment: I have a strange thing, when I select the greatest to see it's value, in the result I get '2014-0' instead of '2014-08-14 17:04:39'

Comment: @darkheir setup a fiddle demo

Comment: I added the fiddle. I tried to make it the more generic possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weirdly it looks like IFNULL has trouble with TIMESTAMPs and INTs, it looks like the following will solve the issue:

```
ORDER BY 
  GREATEST(
    COALESCE(tableA.create_time, 0), 
    COALESCE(tableB.create_time, 0)
  ) 
DESC
```

It seems to return the correct result. I prefer COALESCE to IFNULL anyway as it is more flexible and ANSI standard.

**UPDATE**

On further investigation.. this is incredibly bizarre, the problem you describe only happens on 5.5.32 (of the MySQL fiddle options) and requires the GREATEST or LEAST function, two different TIMESTAMPS, IFNULL round one with an INT replacement, a JOIN to a proper table (not a sub-select) and an ORDER BY to manifest. CRAZY CAKES! Oh and the table must be InnoDB, why ever not!?

The **miminum** I have found to replicate this problem is:

```
  CREATE TABLE tablea (
    create_time timestamp
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

  INSERT INTO `tablea` (create_time) VALUES (NOW());

  SELECT GREATEST(t1.create_time,IFNULL(NOW(),0)) 
    FROM tablea t1
    JOIN tablea t2
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! I found another solution: using TIMESTAMP'19700101' instead of 0 in the IFNULL but I prefer your solution.

Comment: @darkheir COALESCE seems to do the trick either way, strange but true!